# c# Extract String By Regex

Tags: c#, regex

i use Regex extract string text here ..

> +CMGR: "REC UNREAD","MSG","","2013/11/04 14:17:43+28"  0E2A0E270E310E2A0E140E350E040E230E310E1A00200E220E340E190E140E350E150E490E2D0E190E230E310E1A0E040E230E310E1A0E170E380E010E460E040E19

i need select text

> "0E2A0E270E310E2A0E140E350E040E230E310E1A00200E220E340E190E140E350E150E490E2D0E190E230E310E1A0E040E230E310E1A0E170E380E010E460E040E19"

i use code :

```
        string strRegex = @"\b+CMGR: w+\n(\w+)\b";
        RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
        string strTargetString = @"+CMGR: ""REC UNREAD"",""MSG"","""",""2013/11/04 13:52:18+28""" + "\r\n" + @"0E2A0E270E310E2A0E140E350E040E230E310E1A00200E220E340E190E140E350E150E490E2D0E190E230E310E1A0E040E230E310E1A0E170E380E010E460E040E197";

        foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
        {
            if (myMatch.Success)
            {
               return myRegex.Split(strTargetString);
            }
        }
```

is can't extract it..

Thank you

Comment: Where does `from` comes at the end in your result string? Your original string doesn't have it.

Comment: Try something like "\w+$" lol

Comment: @FLCL Was my thinking as well. This seems a little overkill for something which seems very simple.

Comment: May it be better to use something like strTargetString.Split('\n')[1]

Comment: Why don't you select only line 2? If you have multiple entries like the above, maybe it makes sense go through the input line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find last line you may use \w+$ pattern:

```
string strRegex = @"\w+$";    
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
string strTargetString = @"+CMGR: ""REC UNREAD"",""MSG"","""",""2013/11/04 13:52:18+28""" + "\r\n" + @"0E2A0E270E310E2A0E140E350E040E230E310E1A00200E220E340E190E140E350E150E490E2D0E190E230E310E1A0E040E230E310E1A0E170E380E010E460E040E197";
return myRegex.Match(strTargetString);
```

. But the simplest way is to split string into lines and select the second one:

```
strTargetString.Split('\n')[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work with this patter: "^+.+\s"

```
void Main()
{
    string strRegex = @"^\+.+\s";
        RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
        string strTargetString = @"+CMGR: ""REC UNREAD"",""MSG"","""",""2013/11/04 13:52:18+28""" + "\r\n" + @"0E2A0E270E310E2A0E140E350E040E230E310E1A00200E220E340E190E140E350E150E490E2D0E190E230E310E1A0E040E230E310E1A0E170E380E010E460E040E197";

        foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
        {
            if (myMatch.Success)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(myRegex.Split(strTargetString));
            }
        }
}
```

**output**

```
0E2A0E270E310E2A0E140E350E040E230E310E1A00200E220E340E190E140E350E150E490E2D0E190E230E310E1A0E040E230E310E1A0E170E380E010E460E040E197
```