# How to get a string before a string in c#?

Tags: c#, linq, substring

I have a string like,

```
  string1 string2.method();
```

How can I extract string2 from the string? Suppose I have,

```
 string var.ToUpper();
```

How can I get `var` from this string?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Could you add an example that compiles?

Comment: Same question 1h ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541223/how-to-trim-the-end-of-a-string-after-the-first-occurrence-of-a-char-c-sharp

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking...

Comment: input and output examples would **really** help here; this is really really unclear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Extract String By Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763660/c-sharp-extract-string-by-regex)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to parse input string and select matched groups (I use [named groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) here). E.g.

```
string input = "string var.ToUpper();";
string pattern = @"(?<string1>[^\s]+) (?<string2>[^\.]+)\.(?<method>[^\(]+)\(\);";
string string2 = Regex.Match(input, ).Groups["string2"].Value; // "var"
```

Other groups here will have following values:

```
 "string1" : "string" 
 "string2" : "var" 
 "method" : "ToUpper"
```

The first group selects all characters until it meets space. Then second group selects all characters until it meets dot. And last group takes everything between dot and brackets.